# Flash AS2 won't load data from mySQL database! (Using PhP, AS2, and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, flash, actionscript-2

I have a problem! Flash CS6 (AS2) won't load up data from mySQL database. It does successfuly send data from flash to phpmyadmin but flash doesn't load it up D:. I need help please!
So the problem is that whenever I test the movie it traces undefined for the variable I want to load from mySQL. Everything is on one frame including the code and textboxes, buttons, etc. Here is my code:

PHP

```
<?php
require_once('/home/a6934122/public_html/AccountSystem/dbconnect.php');
$testdata1= $_GET['testdata1'];
$testdata2 = $_GET['testdata2'];
$user = $_GET['user'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user = '$user'");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE testdata1 = '$testdata1'");


if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
$status = "&Thestatus = PhP Failed.";
echo($status);
} else {
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$user=$row['user'];
$testdata1=$row2['testdata1'];


$status = "&Thestatus = PhP Successful.";
mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET testdata1='$testdata1', testdata2='$testdata2' WHERE user='$user'");
echo($status);
}
?>
```

FLASH AS2

```
stop();
//Result SendData Code
var result_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
result_lv.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
    if (success) {
        result_ta.text = "We are in business.";
    } else {
        result_ta.text = "Error connecting to server.";
    }
}
//Result SendData Code
//Sending Account Data
SendData = new LoadVars();
//Register Account
register = new LoadVars();
registered = new LoadVars();
//Login Account
login = new LoadVars();
logged = new LoadVars();
//Send Datas
SendData.user = user
submitURL = "http://lumosityentertainment.hostei.com/AccountSystem/PhpLoadTest.php";
  SendData.testdata1 = testdata1;
  SendData.testdata2 = "Testing";
trace(SendData.testdata1);
//now the magic
  SendData.sendAndLoad(submitURL, result_lv, "GET");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the standard way to load variables is to write so onload event for the loadvars object

try this:

```
var result_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
SendData.user = user;
submitURL = "http://lumosityentertainment.hostei.com/AccountSystem/PhpLoadTest.php";
result_lv.testdata1 = testdata1;
result_lv.testdata2 = "Testing";
result_lv.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
    if (success) {
        result_ta.text = "We are in business.";
    } else {
        result_ta.text = "Error connecting to server.";
    }

}
result_lv.sendAndLoad(submitURL, result_lv, "GET");
```

you can find useful information here : [loadvar as2 help](http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/LoadVars.html)

Comment: It doesn't work for me some reason? You sure it's not a PHP error?